Trying to copy files from File Explorer to my HDD with WSL and keep getting a storage space error
I have a Plex server running on Ubuntu Server 24.04 so I formatted my brand new 8 TB NAS drive as EXT4 to store all my media files.  I've set up WSL on my Windows 11 machine and can access the drive. Now I am trying to copy files to the storage mount I made but constantly get an error:
"There is not enough space on Ubuntu. You need an additional 2.02 TB to copy these files."

If I run df -h, you can see my HDD has 6.9 TB available:
tom@Toms-Desktop:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none             16G     0   16G   0% /usr/lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
none             16G  4.0K   16G   1% /mnt/wsl
drivers         931G  527G  405G  57% /usr/lib/wsl/drivers
/dev/sdc       1007G  1.2G  955G   1% /
none             16G   76K   16G   1% /mnt/wslg
none             16G     0   16G   0% /usr/lib/wsl/lib
rootfs           16G  2.2M   16G   1% /init
none             16G  520K   16G   1% /run
none             16G     0   16G   0% /run/lock
none             16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
tmpfs           4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             16G   76K   16G   1% /mnt/wslg/versions.txt
none             16G   76K   16G   1% /mnt/wslg/doc
C:\             931G  527G  405G  57% /mnt/c
D:\             1.9T  662G  1.2T  36% /mnt/d
tmpfs           3.2G   16K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdd1       7.3T   28K  6.9T   1% /mnt/wsl/PHYSICALDRIVE2p1

The drive only has 1 partition:
tom@Toms-Desktop:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    0 388.4M  1 disk
sdb      8:16   0     8G  0 disk [SWAP]
sdc      8:32   0     1T  0 disk /mnt/wslg/distro
                                 /
sdd      8:48   0   7.3T  0 disk
└─sdd1   8:49   0   7.3T  0 part /mnt/wsl/PHYSICALDRIVE2p1

Mount point:
/dev/sdd1 on /mnt/wsl/PHYSICALDRIVE2p1 type ext4 (rw,relatime)

I tried creating a folder named plexfiles under /home/tom/plexfiles, set ownership permissions, and then tried to copy the files and again got the same "needs 2.02 TB" error.
If I create a new text file there, it creates with no issues. If I try to copy over a couple terabytes of data I get the above error. So I am having a space issue but am not sure what to do, this is my first time working with EXT4.
EDIT:
I have made progress some progress. I reformatted, gave 10 GB to the OS and 7.3 TB for storage.
Bash:
tom@Toms-Desktop:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    0 388.4M  1 disk
sdb      8:16   0     8G  0 disk [SWAP]
sdc      8:32   0     1T  0 disk /mnt/wslg/distro
                                 /
sdd      8:48   0   7.3T  0 disk
├─sdd1   8:49   0   9.8G  0 part
└─sdd2   8:50   0   7.3T  0 part /mnt/wsl/PHYSICALDRIVE2p2

PowerShell:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 --partition 2
The disk was successfully mounted as '/mnt/wsl/PHYSICALDRIVE2p2'.
Note: The location will be different if you have modified the automount.root setting in /etc/wsl.conf.
To unmount and detach the disk, run 'wsl.exe --unmount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2'.

I can create a file on it but again get the 2.02 TB free error. So I am confused, everything looks like it's mounted correctly and using the sdd2 partition, but acting like it's using the OS? The file location I'm in is \wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\mnt\wsl\PHYSICALDRIVE2p2 in File Explorer.
Result of df -i:
tom@Toms-Desktop:~$ df -i
Filesystem        Inodes   IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
none             4103210       4   4103206    1% /usr/lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
none             4103210       3   4103207    1% /mnt/wsl
drivers              999 -999001   1000000     - /usr/lib/wsl/drivers
/dev/sdc        67108864   49395  67059469    1% /
none             4103210      40   4103170    1% /mnt/wslg
none             4103210       5   4103205    1% /usr/lib/wsl/lib
rootfs           4102356      12   4102344    1% /init
none             4103210     565   4102645    1% /run
none             4103210       2   4103208    1% /run/lock
none             4103210       1   4103209    1% /run/shm
tmpfs               1024      19      1005    2% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             4103210      52   4103158    1% /mnt/wslg/versions.txt
none             4103210      52   4103158    1% /mnt/wslg/doc
C:\                  999 -999001   1000000     - /mnt/c
D:\                  999 -999001   1000000     - /mnt/d
E:\                  999 -999001   1000000     - /mnt/e
tmpfs             820642      34    820608    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdd2      243871744      11 243871733    1% /mnt/wsl/PHYSICALDRIVE2p2


What does df -i show about this filesystem?

It was too long for a comment so I edited my main post. Here's a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/UXfN8NH

I am not familiar with WSL, but is the following page relevant? There is a 1TB default cap on virtual drive expandability, but I am unsure how this would interact with partition creation.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/disk-space
